# How to get user directory in a cake build

Tags: c#, docker, home-directory, cakebuild

I need the user directory path (absolute) in my cake script, to mount the nuget cache of the build agent to the docker container, that builds the application. How do I get them?

```
Directory("~")
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Does this give error? Or doesn't give the path? Also does this work `var curDir = MakeAbsolute(Directory("~"));`

Comment: No. There is no error. `Information(Directory("~"));` and `Information(MakeAbsolute(Directory("~")));` return both `~` as value, instead of `c:\Users\current_user?`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, on both Windows and *nix, the user home folder is stored in an environment variable.  In which case, you should be able to do something like this:

```
Task("Default")
.Does(() =>
{
    if(IsRunningOnWindows()) {
        Information(EnvironmentVariable("HOMEPATH"));
    } 
    else 
    {
        Information(EnvironmentVariable("HOME"));
    }
});
```

Assuming the above contains what you want, you could then pass the result to `Directory()`.

UPDATE:

Try the following:

```
Task("Default")
    .Does(() =>
{
    if(IsRunningOnWindows()) {
        Information("{0}{1}", EnvironmentVariable("HOMEDRIVE"), EnvironmentVariable("HOMEPATH"));
    } else {
        Information(EnvironmentVariable("HOME"));
    }
});
```

Comment: On Windows the above return `/Users/current_user` as value. The `MakeAbsolute(Directory(pathFromEnv))` return the same. Docker on Windows needs the correct syntax with `c:\Users\current_user`.

Comment: So to confirm, are you running on Windows, or on *nix?

Comment: I want to run on both (we have macOS and Windows build agents), so I need the absolute path of the user home directory. The docker image is linux based with .Net Core build system in it. So I need to pass the volumes with source code, nuget cache and nuget config (private feeds). The last two are stored by default in the user directory of the build agent (on Windows and Unix).

Comment: The Cake build runs on the main host always?

Comment: Updated answer with what I think you are after.  NOTE: I haven't verified what is returned from a *nix machine, as I don't have one to hand.

Comment: @GaryEwanPark thanks. The workaroound works (I tried a similar approach few minutes before your edit).

Comment: Couldn't one just use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)`?

Comment: @me-- the question is whether that returns a usable value on each Operating System or not.  Off the top of my head, I am not sure.

Comment: @me-- and Gary: According to https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/11/07/dotnet-special-folder-api-linux/ it does